# How to make R to read the date consistently

Tags: r, date

The way that I use R to convert the a column to date format in a csv file is

```
df = read.csv(file)    
df %>% mutate(date_column = as.Date(as.character(date_column), format = "%m/%d/%Y"))) #or "%Y-%m-%d"
```

But after read the csv files, I found myself consistently need to change the format between "%m/%d/%Y" and "%Y-%m-%d" for different files. The NA will show in the date column if the format does not "match". But when I opened the files that work with "%m/%d/%Y" and the files that work with %Y-%m-%d", they all seem to have same format to me (month/day/year), so I just don't understand why I need to constantly change the format so that the date column will be read correctly.

Also, there are times that the same file was working fine with a format but the next time I read the file I have to switch the other format so that the date will read properly. I just wonder if there is a way I can keep format consistently? or is there anything I can do before the as.Date() so that I do not need to change the format all the time.

Comment: *"Also, there are times that the same file was working fine with a format but the next time I read the file I have to switch the other format*" ... R will behave the same on the same input. Your statement indicates that you are losing track of what code you are running on what file. Perhaps you are making some changes in the console, but not in your script. Or perhaps you are overwriting the files with different formats. Or maybe there were problems the first time and you didn't notice.

Comment: Other packages have convenience functions, `anytime` does a nice job guessing the correct format. `lubridate` offer `mdy()`, `ymd()` and `dmy()` which don't care about separators, only the order. But dates can be ambiguous and you may need to specify the format. In isolation there's no way to know whether `2/1/2022` is Feb 1 or Jan 2.

Comment: If you need more help, please make your question reproducible by sharing some sample input.